# Problem with nullable decimal with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, oracle11g

I'm using EF with Oracle, and I have a table with a nullable float column.
When I map this table, the column shows up as a Nullable Decimal.

In this table I inserted a row, in the nullable column, I inserted this number:

```
0.0237786257912282
```

Then, I call the table with LINQ:

```
lList = db.EntTest.ToList();
```

Doing that, Visual Studio throws a

> System.InvalidCastException

If I update the record, removing the number and them I call the list again, it works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you add the Code of the class and the structure of the table? It’s easier seeing it than being told.

Comment: I guess the number is not suitable for float. try double or decimal instead.

Comment: Could you show the actual exception message (it should tell you which cast it tries and fails at)?

Comment: You will likely need to specify the precision and scale of the floating point decimal for EF to be happy with the conversion. Have a look at (https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2017/03/29/entity-framework-tip-specifying-decimal-precision/)

Comment: @StevePy, thanks! It works.

Answer (score 0):

As StevePy says, using

```
HasPrecision
```

on **OnModelCreating** function in the **Context.cs** works, for example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntTest>().Property(p => p.NUMBER).HasPrecision(15,30);
}
```